# App logs are sometimes absent from Android bugreport

Tags: android, logcat

I'm trying to get logs from a certain Android application (KDE Connect, if this is relevant), whenever a certain issue/error happens.

- When I **reproduce the issue first**, then connect to the phone over USB (USB debugging enabled) and run `adb bugreport` to capture a bug report -- **I cannot see any logs** from the application, in the zip's logcat. *(I can see other logs from the issue's timeframe though, even from hours earlier, so this doesn't look like a buffer issue)*
- When I **connect to the phone over USB first** (USB debugging enabled), reproduce the issue and then run `adb bugreport` -- **I can see the interesting app logs**, even a backtrace of the interesting errors, in the zip's logcat.

So it would appear there is a difference in what gets logged when USB debugging is connected/enabled, versus when it is not. I'm no Android developer but I cannot find any info on this behaviour.

Does anyone have an explanation (and sources)?

Comment: "I cannot see any logs from the application, in the zip's logcat" -- do you have older entries in that Logcat output? IOW, is the problem that you're not seeing log messages from this app, or are you missing log messages in general from the timeframe of when you reproduced the bug? You might also experiment with increasing the log buffer size (available in Settings > Developer options, at least on newer Android versions).

Comment: @CommonsWare Yeah, I should clarify this -- I can see logs from that general timeframe just fine. Even from hours earlier. The problem is that, I can't see these specific app logs.

What's more -- even after I've seen the app logs using the 2nd procedure, if I take *another* bug report while still plugged in, I no longer see those app logs in this new report.